# How to change the range of my x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a list of 30.000 values. The name of the list is "velocity_x". I just plot them with the following command:

```
plot(velocity_x,'r')
```

the result is shown in the image below (do not pay attention to the dashed line)

[image]

Since I am using that command line, it creates automatically a x-axis of length 30.000. What I would like to do is changing the range of my x-axis in such a way to show the time(s) instead of the iterations where t = 0.0002 * iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
a=np.linspace(0,6,len(velocity_x))
plot(a, velocity_x, 'r' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values by setting 'Xticklabel' see [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12895-relabel-x-axis-tick-marks).

You want to do something like

```
h=gca; %get current axis if you dont have it as a handle already.
set(h, 'Xticklabel', 0:5000*0.0002:5000*0.0002*7); %set correct ticks.
```

Comment: mmm if I use it, it says that "set expected at most 1 arguments".. It seems I cannot do anything with that axis handler. Do I miss any import?

Comment: No, @nivag got confused. He posted Matlab code. I guess you could have stated more clearly that you are using python. The single line of code that you privided is also valid in Matlab.

Comment: Sorry then, thanks for the tip. I will make it clearer the next time. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something along the lines of

```
plot( [i*0.0002 for i in range(len(velocity_x))], velocity_x, 'r' )
```