# modify the x-axis labels in histogram plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I use the following code to plot the histogram. If I want to make the label along the x-axis more fine grained, how to change the code. For instance, the current plot segment the x-axis with 0.2 as interval, can I have 0.05 as interval?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(image_pixel_array,bins=25,color='g')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the range of the x-axis and y-axis in matlibplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337123/how-to-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-and-y-axis-in-matlibplot)

Answer (score 6):

Here,

```
plt.xlim([-3, 3])
plt.ylim([-3, 3])
plt.yticks(np.arange(-3, 3, 0.5))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-3, 3, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

you'll get the ticks 0.5 distance apart in the range of -3 to 3.
Hope this helps.